# Matlab equivalent vectors are not equivalent?

Tags: matlab

for a homework assignment I need to create two equivalent vectors, x1 and x2, using two different methods in Matlab. This should be pretty straight forward however I am getting an error I do not understand.

```
x1 = linspace(2,14,61);
x2 = 2:.2:14;
```

These should create equivalent vectors correct? However, the 8th element of each is supposedly "different".

```
x1(8)
    ans =

    3.4000
x2(8)
    ans = 

    3.4000

x1(8) == x2(8)
    ans =

        0
```

Can someone explain to me why this is? All indexes not a multiple of 8 do not exhibit this behavior. Only the 8th, 16th, etc.

Comment: Hmm this might be it. The examples in that answer also hold for matlab (ex .1+.2 ~= .3)

Comment: I've re-closed this question with a better duplicate as you are specifically asking for behaviour in MATLAB.  However, the previous duplicate link still applies with regards to floating-point precision in its behaviour and its mutual frustration shared by all programmers.

Comment: For completeness, the previous duplicate link can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken